# Are these interfaces the same

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm still trying to come to grips with the many ways of writing the same thing in typesecript.
But this one I'm not sure if they are the same but I'm getting the same results with them so wondering if there is a subtle difference that I'm not getting or its just typescript confusion.

First way:

```
export default interface IApiService {
  send: (url: string) => Promise<string>;
}
```

Second way of writing the interface

```
export default interface IApiService {
  send(url: string): Promise<string>;
}
```

My function itself.

```
  public send = async (url: string) => {
    return fetch(url).then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can declare the type for a function using either `=>` or `:` between the arguments and return type - they mean exactly the same thing. Even though in JavaScript, an arrow function is quite different from a standard function or a method, to TypeScript, the type for a function can be defined either way.

Also, note that since the `send` method doesn't use `await`, you can remove `async` from its definition.